# Safety of Windows during DualBoot upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

My Laptop has both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 . I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. Will my files on Windows or Windows itself be affected by the upgrade ?

Comment: How do you plan to perform the upgrade.

Comment: I don't get your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possibility of upgrading Ubuntu on a dual boot system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797127/possibility-of-upgrading-ubuntu-on-a-dual-boot-system)

Answer (score 1):

I guess in any case the answer should be no the windows files should remain the same if done correctly.

Make sure that windows is not hibernated and is fully shut down during the installation if you use an iso file to install.